# Dynamically resizing JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I've got frame with two JPanels on it in GridLayout :

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400,400);

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    contentPane.add(addPanel());
    contentPane.add(addPanel());
    add(contentPane);
```

`addPanel()` function create JPanel with random colors. When I move mouse cursor on the line between this two panels, I would like to be able to resize dynamically that panels. One becomes wider, and second thiner. How do manage it?

Comment: When you set a container to use GridLayout, [the container is divided into equal-sized rectangles](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`JSplitPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Comment: Although `JSplitPane` is the most logical choice here, I disagree with the 'have to' part.  There is more than one way to skin a cat.  Can you edit your answer?

Comment: Thx a lot. Additionally, do you know how to add listener on divider (double click of mouse)? I'can't post answear ;/

Comment: You can add a MouseListener to the JSplitPane and then check whether the mouse click happend on the divider with the getDividerLocation() and getDividerSize() methods. Note: This is just a first guess, I didn't check if there are better ways

Comment: You have to create BasicSplitPaneUI object, then getDivider() and add MouseListener :)